# Residue of $f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{(z-1)^2}$ at $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find residue of function $f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{(z-1)^2}$ at $z=1$. I know residue of this function at z=0. I got a hint that I needed to use factorial but I don't know exactly how. My teacher said I have to accept residue of that function at $z=1$ as $\frac{1}{(p-1)!}$ which comes to be $\lim_{z \to 1} (\frac{\cos(z)}{(z-1)^2}{(z-1)^2})'!$ which is equal to $\lim_{z \to 1} {-sin(z)}$. I don't know if this answer is true or not. If so I would like someone to explain it to me. I understand the limit part. I just want to know how residue of $f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{(z-1)^2}$ at $z=1$ is equal to $\frac{1}{(p-1)!}$. If it isn't true, I would love to get a solution or help that can get me to solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at a point $z=z_0$ then the residue of $f$ at $z_0$ is $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac d {dz} ((z-z_0)^{2} f(z))$. This can be proved easily using the Laurent series expansion and you will find a proof in almost any  book on Complex Analysis.

There is no $p$ here. The residue is simply $\lim_{z\to1} (-\sin z)=-\sin 1$ since $(\cos z )'=-\sin z$.

Comment: Why do we use derivative? Like how do we get to that point?

Comment: @RaulNəcəfli I have added some details.